# Retrieve 'Page Source' content, like in firefox via right click then 'View Page Source'

Tags: powershell

In Firefox you can right click on any page, then click on `View Page Source`, this will give you  some code that looks to be HTML.
I am looking to do the same thing in PowerShell. There are many times I have found myself doing this and would like to have a PowerShell approach.

I am trying to find a consistent way of obtaining the Chanell  ID of a YouTube channel, in PowerShell. [THIS](https://www.ghacks.net/2022/08/01/how-to-subscribe-to-youtube-rss-feeds-without-third-party-services/) guide seems to be offering a reliable method but it relies on this very **View Page Source** method found in Firefox.

So I have tried

```
$var = invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.youtube.com/@houdini3d/featured
```

This does return some HTML information about the page.

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-GB" dir="ltr"><head><style nonce="sNb8Va34AquZa4m4EwgJTg">
                    a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
                      color: #1a73e8;
                      text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    body {
                      font-family: Ro…
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I tried comparing the text content from a Firefox window and the value in `$Var.RawContent`. They don't seem to be the same thing.  I also checked `$var.Content` not the same either.

by comparing I mean manually by in a text editor.

Is `invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.youtube.com/@houdini3d/featured` the wrong way to go about this?

I don't know any web "Programming Languages" like HTML/CSS, so I am in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Internet Explorer ComObject to do this.

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$IE.Navigate('https://www.youtube.com/@houdini3d')
While($IE.Busy){Start-Sleep -Second 1}
If($IE.Document.IHTMLDocument2_body.innerHTML -match 'browse_id","value":"(.+?)"'){$Matches[1]}else{"Channel ID not found"}
```

Comment: Is IE COM object still working these days, on Win 11?

Comment: I don't know, I still use Win10 on my dev box where I wrote that.

Comment: Yes, it still works, I just tested with recently updated Win 11. The COM object is still serviced by iexplore.exe. If you try to directly launch iexplore.exe, it will redirect to Edge though. [IE11 deprecation FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549). **tl;dr:** Edge IE mode is also provided by iexplore.exe and IE mode will be supported "through at least 2029". So we can conclude that IE COM object will be available as long.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician , IE?! You absolute mad lad, thank you!

Comment: As in all other things, it appears that Internet Explorer will be slow in dyeing as well.